# LDAP connection in C#

Tags: c#, ldap, ldapconnection

I am new to LDAP. I am trying to connect to LDAP using my certificate credentials and no user name and password. The code i am using is

```
    LdapConnection ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldap://192.168.10.5:636"));
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;
    LdapSessionOptions options = ldapConnection.SessionOptions;
    options.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    options.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate();
    cert.Import(@"c:\certfolder\mycert.crt");
    ldapConnection.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    ldapConnection.Bind();
```

The above code is giving me error "The LDAP server is unavailable" when compiler tries to run line ldapConnection.Bind();.

When i place a breakpoint at line1 it gives the following error.
base{system.DirectoryService.Protocols.DirectroyException}{"The server cannot handle directory request."}

Comment: Try without prefix since LdapDirectoryIdentifier is made only for Ldap so it might be causing the problem.

Comment: If won't help give me a comments I'll try your code and will find an issue.

Comment: @MajkeloDev I have tried without "LDAP" just the "192.168.10.5:636" still giving me the same error.

Comment: Ok i'll test it and soon gonna give You feedback.

Comment: @MajkeloDev did you get a chance to to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Same code without prefix worked for me.

```
LdapConnection nconnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(LDAPurl, LDAPPort));
```

or

```
LdapConnection nconnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("localhost:10636"));
```

Both are working fine.